# What is the meaning of the rollback in PostgreSql and when to use it?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

What is the meaning of the rollback in PostgreSql and when to use it?

As far as I understand if one is making some transaction then via rollback he/she can be assured that this transaction will rollback (will not happen).
Description from the official documentation: "Description. ROLLBACK rolls back the current transaction and causes all the updates made by the transaction to be discarded".

Now I don't understand why somebody will want to write a transaction and then implicitly insist on its termination?
It seems to me, that nobody should use the rollback, and instead they should stick to the commit because commit lets the transaction happen if it is correct and terminate it otherwise.

Comment: A transaction could consist of multiple inserts and updates, and the failure of one of them might require that all of them be rolled back, to ensure that the data is kept in a consistent state.  For example, a bank transfer must update the source account and the destination account.  If either update fails the entire transaction must be rolled back, otherwise one of the accounts will have the wrong balance.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Ok, now if we use rollback we won't have any undesired data. However, we won't have any 'good' data too. For example,  we have a table like this                        
CREATE TABLE T(id INT, value INT, CHECK(value >= 10));
INSERT INTO T(id, value) VALUES (1, 10);
And a transaction:                                                                                                   BEGIN; 
UPDATE T SET value=value+1 WHERE id=1;  
ROLLBACK;  as far as I understand it is a perfectly valid transaction. However, it will terminate because of the usage of ROLLBACK. Am I right?

Comment: Generally rollbacks are only performed if an error is detected (for example by an application that is executing the SQL statements).  In the console, you might use them to experiment, for example by performing an update, querying to see if it has had the desired effect, and then committing if the data is correct, or rolling back if it is not.

Comment: @snakecharmerb So, ROLLBACK will let me do the transaction if it is valid and will terminate it entirely otherwise, meanwhile, COMMIT will perform the valid part and terminate at the invalid part of the query. Am I right? P.S. Unfortunately, I am not able to experiment with my example because for some reason while using ROLLBACK it gives the following error: relation "T" already exists.

Comment: "*COMMIT will perform the valid part and terminate at the invalid part of the query*" - **NO**. commit commits **everything**, not just "some" of the statements. The definition of a transaction is: either **all** (!) statements succeed or **none**. If one of them failed, **all** of them need to be rolled back. You can't commit just the "good ones". It's all or nothing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then what is the difference between ROLLBACK and COMMIT? Both of them will terminate if the invalid query is given. However, I know commit will perform the query if it is valid and according to what I understand from the comments ROLLBACK will also let the valid query be executed.

Comment: rollback reverts **all** changes made in that transaction and commit makes (**all** of) them permanent. There is no such thing as a "partial commit" or "partial rollback". It's all or nothing. And if there was an error, Postgres will force you to do a rollback.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, it does not make sense to use rollback without commit in the transaction since it will revert all the changes if we do so. Instead, if we use rollback with commit then we will be assured that no invalid query will be executed and will make only valid changes permanent. Please, say that I got it ))

Comment: you either use `rollback` **or** `commit` - never both. There is no such thing as "rollback with commit"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok. As you said rollback reverts all changes so it doesn't let the transaction happen even if it is the correct one.  If so then it is kind of useless and I still don't understand why should someone use rollback instead of commit. Anyway, thank you for the time and effort you put on these comments!

Comment: You need to distinguish between errors caused by invalid SQL or integrity violations like duplicate keys, where Postgres will require a rollback, and program errors, such as when one half of a bank transfer fails.  In this second category the _programmer_ must decide whether a transaction is committed or rolled back.  Rollback is a tool, the programmer must decide when it should be used.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The irony is that I don't understand when it should be used )) I guess, I will go with what LaurenzAlbe wrote in the answers and will not use rollback ever since if I wrote a transaction I don't want it to be 'undone' no matter what. I want it to be executed if it is 'true' and terminated if it is invalid.

Comment: Look at commit as the "save" button on your app and rollback as the "cancel" button.  As a developer do not underestimate the power of rollback. Assume you have a series of DML that is not quite what you need, but cannot uncover the exactly the point where things go wrong. You can run the DML and view the changes then rollback leaving the database as it started, repeat the test in the next round of tests, without having to reload. Or a production issue needing correct asap. You can run the proposed fix and validate it, then commit (save) or rollback (cancel) as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transaction can consist of several database statements, and there may be application code interleaved.

Imagine a simple money transfer:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT amount FROM account WHERE account_nr = 432 FOR UPDATE;
/* do some calculation in the application */
UPDATE account SET amount = 543.23 WHERE account_nr = 432;
SELECT amount FROM account WHERE account_nr = 123 FOR UPDATE;
/* do another calculation in the application */
UPDATE account SET amount = 1903.4 WHERE account_nr = 123;
COMMIT;
```

Now at any point you could encounter a problem, for example:

- The second `SELECT` statement may return no result, because there is no such account.
- The second `UPDATE` could fail, because it violates a database constraint.
- The second calculation in the application may cause an error condition.

If something like that happens, you need to abort the transaction and undo its work. For example, you cannot allow the change to account 432 to become visible.

The proper way to do that in a relational database is to issue a `ROLLBACK`, then all that will happen automatically.

Transactions are a service for the user to make it easy to write reliable and robust code.

Comment: ROLLBACK will let me do the transaction if it is valid and will terminate it entirely otherwise, meanwhile, COMMIT will perform the valid part and terminate at the invalid part of the query. Am I right?

Comment: No. `COMMIT` only works if all statements have succeeded and confirms the transaction. `ROLLBACK` undoes **everything** that happened in the transaction.